# ISO 8601 format date for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, timezone, iso8601, formatdatetime

I have string containing an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted date-time value (ex: `2013-05-21T15:00:00+0200`) and time zone (ex: `Europe/Rome`).

What is the best [Postgres data type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype.html) to represent this date format?

Comment: Just for future questions, please always mention your exact PostgreSQL version (`select version()`). It isn't important for this particular question, but it often will be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Type "timestamp with time zone" is what you want.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html

Comment: I have a string in this format: 2013-05-21T15:00:00+0200" and Timezone: "Europe/Rome" How can I use this string into a INSERT query if I use a data type as "timestamp with time zone"?
Need I a particular function to conversion a ISO 8601 datetime into timestamp with time zone format?

Comment: Postgres doesn't store timezone, it just recalculate timestamp to server timezone. And your timezone is specify by "+200". But INSERT INTO tab(somecol) VALUES('2013-05-21T15:00:00+0200') should work